# R gsub and perl

Tags: regex, r, perl, gsub

Hi I am trying to peform a specific pattern matching.

I want to stand. street names.

```
y <- c("Straße des 18 JAN.")

gsub("(.*)([1-3]?[0-9]\\.?)(JAN\\.?U?A?R?)(.*)","\\1 \\2 JANUAR \\4",y, perl=T)
```

What I want is that it keeps everything but rewrites the bracket 3 to JANUAR, so far i could not handle that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression has to be

```
gsub("(.*)([1-3]?[0-9]\\.?) (JAN\\.?U?A?R?)(.*)","\\1\\2 JANUAR\\4",y, perl=TRUE)

# [1] "Straße des 18 JANUAR"
```

I added a whitespace () before the term beginning with `(JAN`. Furthermore, I removed the whitespaces between `\\1` and `\\2` and between `JANUAR` and `\\4`.